# Xubuntu guest session crashing

Tags: xubuntu, login, guest-session

We have three computers at our facility for our guests to use. All of them are installed with Xubuntu 14.04.

One has issue with the guest session. Immediately after login it crashes and returns back to the login screen. I am not able to find out cause, nor solution. Perhaps I should try copying the files from /etc/skel/ from one of the cunctional PC's to this troublesome one and see if that helps.

What would be the cause? I have examined some of the logs, but I can't find anything that I would see to be causing this.

Comment: I copied the /etc/skel/ from the functional system to this one, but it did not help, the session is still crashing.

Comment: Have you customized the guest session somehow?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It was set up by someone else before me. To me, the configuration on all these three computers look the same. Only one has the problem.

Comment: Can you show us (by editing your question) the contents of `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` right after such a crash?

Comment: I gave up as it was taking too much time - and reinstalled the system. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up as it was taking too much time - and reinstalled the system. It solved the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/639669)

Comment: I am the author. And I cannot continue troubleshooting the problem, because it was too time consuming and I reinstalled the entire system on those public computers. Thus, I don't have any system left with that problem. Should I remove my answer? Should I delete my entire question?

Comment: no, it's already been flagged for closing.